# MotionLayout with touch region blocks RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout

I have a layout with a ViewPager at the top and a TextView + RecyclerView below it. When scrolling the RecyclerView, it should go over the ViewPager and the ViewPager should be animated (fade out + scroll up). To achieve this, I used a MotionLayout.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutHeader"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_main"
        tools:motionProgress="0">

<!-- This is the view that will be animated. -->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCards"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerCards"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator3
                android:id="@+id/circleIndicatorCards"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small"
                app:ci_drawable="@drawable/shape_viewpager_indicator_selected"
                app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/shape_viewpager_indicator_default"
                app:ci_width="@dimen/indicator_circle"
                app:ci_height="@dimen/indicator_circle"
                app:ci_animator="@animator/animator_pager_indicator"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPagerCards"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<!-- The 3 views below will scroll up -->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewTransactionsBackground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_surface"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerViewTransactions"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            style="@style/TextView.Header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/spacing_regular"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/spacing_smaller"
            android:text="@string/dashboard_transactions_header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutCards"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTransactions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/listitem_transaction"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

This is the motion scene that goes with it:

```
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"/>

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/expanded">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/layoutCards"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/viewTransactionsBackground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerViewTransactions"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutCards"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/recyclerViewTransactions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/collapsed"
        app:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/expanded">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/layoutCards"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/textViewTransactionsHeader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

What happens here is that I can scroll up by swiping any of the 3 bottom views (the RecyclerView, the header TextView above it, or the background view), so that is good, but I can only scroll back down by swiping the RecyclerView. The header TextView doesn't respond to touch anymore. This seems te be caused by the ViewPager because when I replace that with a dummy view, scrolling down works.

Another feature that I would like to work around is that I can start scrolling up anywhere in the MotionLayout except for the region of the ViewPager. So scrolling up on the circle indicator starts the animation, which I don't want. I tried adding a touch region but that breaks the motion. When using `app:touchRegionId="@id/viewTransactionsBackground"` (this is the exact region I want), the RecyclerView doesn't scroll anymore. When using `app:touchRegionId="@id/recyclerViewTransactions"` the RecyclerView will jump the top (end state) when I start dragging.

How would I go about swiping the area surrounding the RecyclerView and not the rest of the layout while still being able to scroll in the RecyclerView?

Comment: i know it's been 3 years but... did you find a solution to activate the OnSwipe on the whole view without intercepting all the click/swipe events from the childs (recyclerview, header ..) ?? Thx